# ProgressBar not spinning during async load

Tags: android, xamarin

When I open a `Fragment` I try to show a `ProgressBar`, populate a `RecyclerView`, update `NotifyChange` to `RecyclerView` and then hide the `ProgressBar`.

Right now the ProgressBar isn't spinning. I think it has to do with SetRecyclerViewItems being executed on the UI Thread but if I don't do that I get an error saying that the UI can only be updated in the UI thread.

Fragment:

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            /* Initializing elements code removed */

            SetRecyclerView();

            return view;
        }

    public async override void OnStart()
            {
                base.OnStart();

                ShowProgressBar();
                await LoadAsync();
                HideProgressBar();
            }

            private async Task LoadAsync()
            {
                await Task.Run(() => {
                    SetRecyclerViewItems();
                });

            }

            private void SetRecyclerView()
            {
                mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mRecyclerView.Context);
                mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                mAdapter = new TransactionsRecyclerAdapter(this.Activity, mTransactions, dateFormat);
                mAdapter.ItemClick += MAdapter_ItemClick;
                mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(mAdapter);
            }

            private void SetRecyclerViewItems(List<PaymentListItemViewModel> transactions = null)
            {
                Activity.RunOnUiThread(() => {

                    if (transactions == null)
                        transactions = GetTransactions();
                    mAdapter.NotifyChange(transactions);
                    SetTotal();
                });
            }
```

Adapter.NotifyChange

```
public void NotifyChange(List<PaymentListItemViewModel> transactions)
        {
            mTransactions = transactions;
            NotifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Why isn't the ProgressBar spinning?
Is the way I'm populating new data to the Adapter correct (sending in a new list and then `NotifyDataSetChanged`?

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/login_background">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/transactionsProgressBar">
        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerViewTransactions"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In OnCreateView:

```
mLayoutProgressBar = view.FindViewById<RelativeLayout>(Resource.Id.transactionsProgressBar);
```

Show/Hide ProgressBar:

```
private void ShowProgressBar()
                {
                    mLayoutProgressBar.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                }

                private void HideProgressBar()
                {
                    mLayoutProgressBar.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                }
```

Comment: Obviously it's because RunOnUiThread inside SetRecyclerViewItems which is just a shortcut for Handler.post which returns immediately and makes those all async, await and task useless

Comment: What are GetTransactions and SetTotal and how long do they take?

Comment: That was what I thought but as stated if I don't run it within the UI thread throws an exception saying that "View can only be changed within the UI thread". How would I run two UI items (ProgressBar and SetRecyclerViewItems) separately?

Comment: @Luke On creation the Adapter is populated with an empty list and then I get the data to be used in the ReyclerView using GetTransactions. It takes around 1 second to process. SetTotal is an empty method at the moment.

Comment: You obviously should only run GetTransactions in task and await for its results

Comment: @Jefecito show your code of progressbar.

Comment: @VetaLio Post updated

Comment: @Jefecito did you try to use "break points"? How looks your axml code with progressBar? I think the main problem is with your axml code,so you need to show your progress bar overlay other views. Or you can just use simple DialogFragment(Or AlertDialog) with Progres Bar. 
https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/15155286/22170473/6a38a9ec-df86-11e6-9854-9e989f44c370.gif See this gif and tell me if its okay for you. i Can show how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put the loading onto a separate thread by using `Task.Run()` but in there you marshal back to the UI thread to update your adapter (`Activity.RunOnUiThread()`), this will block the UI thread and your spinner stops running.

Depending on what your `SetTotal()` method is doing, you should only have the call to `mAdapter.NotifyChange(transactions);` being executed on the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I had a lot of calculations going in OnBindViewHolder (which blocked the UI thread) and with your assistance I now load all the data async and only send in the actual data to the RecyclerView.